# Spark authentication and encryption on spark standalone cluster with spark.master.rest.enabled=true

Tags: apache-spark

How can we do authentication and encryption on spark standalone cluster with spark.master.rest.enabled=true.
Getting below error on master while enabling authentication:
ERROR util.SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[main,5,main]

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The RestSubmissionServer does not support authentication via spark.authenticate.secret.  Either turn off the RestSubmissionServer with  =false, or do not use authentication.
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master.<init>(Master.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master$.startRpcEnvAndEndpoint(Master.scala:1076)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master$.main(Master.scala:1058)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master.main(Master.scala)
```